# Sample size calculation in an analytical cross-sectional study

Tags: sample-size, cross-section, analytical

I want to calculate the sample size for an analytical cross-sectional study I'm planning on doing. I want to find out if there's an association between an exposure  and a disorder.
I will be finding out the number of people exposed and non exposed who develop and do not develop the disorder.

What are the values I need from other studies and the formula I need to substitute them into to find the sample size?

Comment: Depends on the approach to sample size calculations you are going to use. It seems your hypothesis could possible be tested by a chi-square test, in which case you could use R's pwr package's pwr.chisq.test function, for which you'd only need to derive the expected effect size from existing literature.

Comment: @Sointu How would I calculate sample size if if I use Odds Ratio to measure the association? Would an Odds ratio even be valid in this study?

Comment: So, it sounds like you are planning to use logistic regression and report your estimates as odds ratios? There are online calculators you can use to get some guidelines about sample size, such as this: https://sample-size.net/logistic-regression-sample-size/ , but I believe simulation approach would be better. See [this article](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0742-8) for instance.